# Why does my implementation of the Metropolis algorithm converge incorrectly for a non-uniform prior distribution?

Tags: metropolis-hastings

I am trying to estimate the integral of sine from $0$ to $\pi$ using the Metropolis algorithm from a prior distribution of $p(x) = e^{-(x-\pi/2)^2}$
$$\int_0^\pi \sin(x)\,\text{d}x$$ The integral ought to converge to $2$ but instead it repeatedly converges to $1.16\pm0.01$:

[image]

Curiously enough, if I instead run the same script for a uniform distribution as the prior distribution, the integral converges to the right number:

[image]

I would appreciate to know why my initial approach leads to an incorrect estimate of the integral. I'm also a bit confused as to why the sample distribution follows that of the prior and not that of the posterior. Also, should my "candidate" function follow the uniform distribution or that of $p(x)$? Choosing the latter  the integral converges to $1.13$ instead.

(I try to follow [these explanations](https://web.northeastern.edu/afeiguin/phys5870/phys5870/node80.html). I believe my code follows the pseudocode exactly, except perhaps for computing the actual ensemble average in step 9, where instead of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i^n f(x_i)$ I compute $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i^n f(x_i)/p(x_i)$. However, doing the latter causes the integral to again converge incorrectly, to $0.80$.)

```py
#Define bounds of sampling:
x_1, x_2 = 0., np.pi

n = 3000  #Number of trials
x = 0.    #Initial x
X = np.zeros((n, 1))
I_conv = np.zeros(n)

#Integrand
def f(x):
    if x_1 <= x <= x_2:
        return np.sin(x)
    else:
        return 0

#The probability density of a sample x
def p(x):
    #Uniform distribution over [x_1, x_2]:  return 1/(x_2-x_1)
    return np.exp(-(x-np.pi/2)**2)

#Given a current location x, propose a new location x2
def candidate(x):
    #Uniform sampling over [x_1, x_2]:
    return np.random.uniform(x_1,x_2)

#Metropolis algorithm
for i in range(n):
    X[i] = x
    x2 = candidate(x)
    if np.random.uniform() < np.minimum(1.0, p(x2)/p(x)):
        x = x2
    d = f(x)/p(x)
    I += d
    I_conv[i] = I/(i)
integral = I/n
print('MCMC approx: ',integral)
integral, I = 0., 0.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is not related with Metropolis-Hastings [which is clearly dispensable in this case] but with the feature that $p(x)$ is not a density as it does not integrate to one. What you obtain instead is a Monte Carlo approximation of the ratio
$$\int_0^\pi \sin(x)\,\text{d}x\, \Big/ \int_0^\pi p(x)\,\text{d}x = 2 \big/ 1.73$$
In the Uniform case, the density is properly normalised.

> As a side remark, I do not understand what the OP calls *prior* and
>   *posterior*, as there is no data involved in this question.